# StackOverflow exception while adding one array list to another

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I and getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError` while executing below code,

```
public class Insertion {
    private static ArrayList integers1 = new ArrayList();
    private static ArrayList integers2 = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collections.addAll(integers1, 1, 2, 3);
        Collections.addAll(integers2, 5, 6, 7);

        integers1.add(integers2);
        System.out.println(integers1);
        integers2.add(integers1);
        System.out.println(integers2);
    }
}
```

Please explain why?

Comment: Always provide a full stack trace when handling with unexplained exceptions. Showing the output of the print statements might help as well.

Comment: private static ArrayList integers1 = new ArrayList(); it is a old style of programming in Java.

Comment: What are you expecting `integers1.add(integers2);` to do? Add each element from `integers2` to `integers1` (hint: it doesn't do that)?

Comment: This could have been an interview question. "What happens when this code is executed?".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The StackOverflow is happenning when you try to print the list. 

You have two lists: `integers1=[1,2,3,integers2]` and `integers2=[5,6,7,integers1]`

When you try to print `integers2`, you actually print:

```
[1,2,3,integers1.toString()]
```

and `integers1.toString()` is `[5,6,7,integers2.toString()]`, which in its turn invoke `integers1.toString()` again and again. This results in infinite loop that ends only when stack is overflowed.

The theoretical result of this print will be `[1,2,3,5,6,7,1,2,3,5,6,7,... (infinite repeat)]`, and this is done via recursion - but at some point, the stack is full and the program breaks.

Comment: +1 That is a nice description of how the infinite loop unfolds.

Answer (score 7):

In this line:

```
integers1.add(integers2);
```

you are adding an entire array list into another array list. And when you do this:

```
integers2.add(integers1);
```

you create a circular reference. Boom - an exception occurs when you try and print.

If you had used generics, this wouldn't have happened. I assume you only wanted to keep integers in your list, thus this declaration would have caused your code to fail to compile:

```
private static ArrayList<Integer> integers1 = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<Integer> integers2 = new ArrayList<>();

// ...

// The method add(Integer) in the type ArrayList<Integer> is not applicable 
// for the arguments (ArrayList<Integer>)
integers1.add(integers2);
```

Comment: @Duncan-Man I was just emphasising the major event here---point of circular reference!

Answer (score 4):

You already got nice explanations to your infinite loop and StackOverflow.

Now, assuming this circular reference wasn't your intent, you probably wanted to add the elements of one list to the other. This is done with `addAll` :

```
integers1.addAll(integers2);
integers2.addAll(integers1);
```